# How to use the array of values in the WHERE clause of my query

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010, kendo-ui

I am using asp.net mvc3. I want to pass an array from view to the controller using parameterMap as shown below. In my view:

```
     parameterMap:
            function (data, options) {
               if (options === "read") {
               sessionStorage.setItem("value","array");
               val = sessionStorage.getItem("value"); // contains array
               return { model: JSON.stringify(val) }; //passing array to controller
                }
            }
```

In controller:

```
  public ActionResult SearchDetails( string model)     
  {
     var query = (from ......).where();//want to compare array values in controller
        
  }
```

but I am not able to retrieve those values in the controller. How can I retrieve these array of values in my controller without using looping statements?

My array contains only integer values (ids), while debugging the when I put cursor at the parameter of action method the values are coming in ""[{\"id\":1},{\"id\":2}]"" format. How can I use this array of values in my WHERE clause of my query?

Comment: public ActionResult SearchDetails( string model) {}
   while debugging ,when i put cursor on model I am getting the values like "\"[{\\\"id\\\":1 "id\\\":2}]\"".I want to retrieve these array of values in my controller and use those values in my where clause of the query

Comment: Are you asking that how can you get the values as array instead of a string?

Comment: actually my array contains two values {1,2} it is displaying in the above format as i mentioned in last post.I want to retrieve the each value in the array in my controller and compare those values in the lambda expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are bound and determined to stick with the string input, I would think a call to **Split** would work. However, it would be much easier if you changed from bringing it in as a string to just bringing in the model. Have you tried something like:

```
  public ActionResult SearchDetails( model model)     
  {
     var query = (from ......).where();//want to compare array values in controller

  }
```

are you trying to do something equivalent to a SQL IN? If that is the case then use .Contains in your query. For example:

```
public ActionResult SearchDetails(model model)
{
    var query = from d in context.data
                where model.Contains(d.id)
                select d;
}
```